# Selection sorting an instance of an object of type ArrayList of objects giving weird results

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, selection-sort

I have a CarLot class, a Car class, and a CarLotApp class to set up a GUI for it. The CarLot is an ArrayList of Car objects. I have methods in CarLot that selection sort the CarLot based off of instance variables in Car (make, model, mpg,etc.)

For example:

```
public ArrayList<Car> getSortedDescMPG() {
    ArrayList<Car> lotSortedByMPG = new ArrayList<Car>(myCars);
    Car car; 
        for (Car c : lotSortedByMPG) {
            double currentMax = c.getMPG();
            car = c;
            int currentMaxIndex = lotSortedByMPG.indexOf(c);

            for (Car c2 : lotSortedByMPG) {
                if (currentMax < c2.getMPG()) {
                    currentMax = c2.getMPG();
                    car = c2;
                    currentMaxIndex = lotSortedByMPG.indexOf(c2);
                }
            }
            if (currentMaxIndex != lotSortedByMPG.indexOf(c)) {
                lotSortedByMPG.set(currentMaxIndex, c);
                lotSortedByMPG.set(lotSortedByMPG.indexOf(c), car);
            }
        }
        return lotSortedByMPG;
}
```

I'm trying to get the sorted list into a TextArea in CarLotApp. In CarLotApp I also have three buttons, one to add a car, one to sort asc and one to sort desc, and a combo box to choose what instance variable to sort by.

```
class SortDesc extends WidgetViewerActionEvent {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {            

        txtrSortedCarLot.setText("");
        if (cmbSortOptions.getSelectedIndex() == 0) 
            txtrSortedCarLot.setText(myCarLot.toString());
        else if (cmbSortOptions.getSelectedIndex() == 1)
            txtrSortedCarLot.setText(CarLot.toString(myCarLot.getSortedDescMPG()));
        else if (cmbSortOptions.getSelectedIndex() == 2)
            etc...
    }
}
```

The main issue is that the ArrayLists that were spat out from my sorting methods were out of order. I looked for similar posts but they all linked to one that focused on using a comparator to sort. I want to do this without useing compartors. So then I didn't really know what to search for since for what I can tell my sorting methods should work. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `if (currentMax < c2.getSomeMPG()) { currentMax = c2.getMPG()`:  it looks like you're testing if one thing should become the new `currentMax` but then making some entirely other thing the new `currentMax`.

Comment: It's updating the currentMax. If the current thing we think is the maximum turns out to be smaller than something else, it can't be the actual maximum so we update it to the new currentMax we just found.

Comment: You just described the way it's **supposed** to work.  I'm saying that's not what it's doing.  You compared to `c2.getSomeMPG()`, so `c2.getSomeMPG()` should be the new `currentMax`, yes?  But you then set `currentMax` to `c2.getMPG()`, not `c2.getSomeMPG()`.  Was that just a typo?  Or are `c2.getSomeMPG()` and `c2.getMPG()` magically the same thing?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes that was a typo I fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

When you do selection sort, the beginning of the array or list is becoming sorted, and you shouldn't look there for a maximum value. You rather want to find the maximum value in the *remainder* of the list, which is still unsorted. Your code was instead repeatedly finding the same car with maximum MPG.

Here's a working selection sort:

```
public static ArrayList<Car> getSortedDescMPG() {
    ArrayList<Car> lotSortedByMPG = new ArrayList<>(myCars);
    for (int i = 0; i < lotSortedByMPG.size(); i++) {
        // At the beginning of each iteration, cars 0 through (i-1) are sorted

        // Find the max-MPG car with index in the range (i, size-1) inclusive
        Car carI = lotSortedByMPG.get(i);
        int maxIndex = i;
        Car maxCar = carI;
        int maxMPG = carI.getMPG();
        for (int j = i + 1; j < lotSortedByMPG.size(); j++) {
            Car curCar = lotSortedByMPG.get(j);
            int curMPG = curCar.getMPG();
            if (curMPG > maxMPG) {
                maxIndex = j;
                maxCar = curCar;
                maxMPG = curMPG;
            }
        }

        // Now swap the max-MPG car (at index maxIndex) with car i (at index i)
        lotSortedByMPG.set(i, maxCar);
        lotSortedByMPG.set(maxIndex, carI);
    }
    return lotSortedByMPG;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the first for loop take care of finding the same car twice?

Comment: Ooh, I see. I shouldn't have used a for each loop